# Simply Two Dimensional

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm trying to solve this exercise.

https://gyazo.com/043018a2e547b4bfb4ef9eb1adfd707a

However with my current code I am getting this as an output.

https://gyazo.com/13ed434ec876e145931b45e6d12a02fc

Currently this is the code I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define r 3
#define c 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, j;
float *a[r], sum;

freopen("testdata2", "r", stdin);

for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
  float *row = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*c);
  for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
  scanf("%f", &row[i]);
}
  a[i] = row;
}

printf("The average values for the three rows are: ");
for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
  sum = 0;
  for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
{
  sum += a[i][j];
}
  printf("%.2f", sum/c);
}

printf("\nThe average values for the three columns are: ");
for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
  sum = 0;
  for(j = 0; j < r; i++)
{
  sum += a[i][j];
}
  printf("%.2f", sum/r);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case you think you use a 2D array: You don't. A pointer is not an array, nor is an array of pointers a 2D array.

Comment: Review `for(i = 0; i < c; i++) ...  for(j = 0; j < r; i++) ...  sum += a[i][j];`

Comment: I can't read it anyway.  Fix the indentation.

Answer (score -1):

its not correct cause you declare

```
float *a[r] /* r = 3 */
int i;
```

and call

```
for(i = 0; i < r; i++) {
  float *row = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*c);

  for(i = 0; i < c; i++) { // just write for(int i =0; i < c ; i++) {
    scanf("%f", &row[i]);  // or use j here;
  }

  a[i] = row; // i = c /* 5 */ here
              // a[4] and a[5] are not located
}
```

in best way you will get wrong data , acoording to some data in memory;
the other way your program will crush by access violation , trying to use memroy taken by other program

right way it will be

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    float *row = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*c);

    for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) { 
        scanf("%f", &row[j]);
    }

    a[i] = row;                     
}
```